# ForgotPassword PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am writing a login form with PHP and Mysql.

I did everything its just the forgot password that is not working.

It sends me email confirmation but it does not update the password in the database.

First is the forgot page, then sends an email and redirect me to the `confirm_pass.html` page where is the form for the two passwords and on this page executes the `confirm_pass.php` where is doing everything, except updating the password in the database.

Please help.

```
 <?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') { 

// Make sure the two passwords match
if ( $_POST['newpassword'] == $_POST['confirmpass'] ) { 

    $new_password = password_hash($_POST['newpassword'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    $email = $mysqli->escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $confirm_code  = md5(rand().$password);

    $result = "UPDATE `mv_db`.`users` SET `password`='$new_password', `confirm`='$confirm_code' WHERE `email`='$email'";

    if ( $mysqli->query($result) ) {
        header("location: login.html");    

    }

}
else {
    $_SESSION['message'] = " The two passwords you entered don't match, try again!";
    header("location: error.php");    
}

}
?>
```

Comment: your html form?

Comment: WHERE `email`='$email'  > here please remove '' from $email

Comment: https://codepen.io/NTodorova/pen/wpZrgZ This is the htm

Comment: @krishnPatel huh?

Comment: define "not working". Start by checking for errors via php and the query; you're not doing that.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner it is not updating the password in the database. The password stays the same. What do you mean by checking for errors?

Comment: Error reporting https://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php would have signaled an undefined index error.

Answer (score 2):

Your `$_POST['email']` is not defined, because there is no "email" field in your HTML form.

So nothing is updated in database, because there is no matching record.

Comment: heyy, I have this two       hidden inputs in the html                                                                         <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?= $email ?>">    
<input type="hidden" name="confirm" value="<?= $confirm_code?>">